# Не создаётся канал в категории discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Этот кусок кода даёт автору команды роль, пишет ему в лс что он молодец и создаёт канал:

```
author = ctx.message.author
guild = bot.get_guild(айди сервера)
role = guild.get_role(айди роли)
await author.add_roles(role)
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name = 'Тест', category = 'айди_категории')
await author.send('крч да ты молодец')
```

Почему-то, после добавления category = 'айди_категории', бот перестал работать, пишет:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`

Что делать чтобы канал создался именно в категории? Почему не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Открываем в документации список свойств и методов класса [`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) и находим там метод, который вы используете для создания текстового канала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываем [**описание метода**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.create_text_channel):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И видим, что параметр `category` принимает тип [`discord.CategoryChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.CategoryChannel), а вы вместо этого передаете строку (`str`). Библиотека при создании канала пытается получить `id` категории, обращаясь к свойству класса, подразумевая, что вы передали ей объект категории, но тут выясняется, что вы передали строку (`str`), у которой нет свойства `id`. Об этом и написано в ошибке:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

---

**Что нужно сделать?**

Нужно получить объект категории и передать именно его в качестве параметра.

Возвращаемся к списку свойств и методов класса [`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) и видим свойство `categories`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которое возвращает список объектов категорий каналов, нужного нам типа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зная `id` нужной категории получим ее из этого списка либо руками, либо встроенной функцией библиотеки `discord.utils.get()`:

```py
category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=733276420512439996)
```

Теперь, имея объект категории создаем канал:

```py
await guild.create_text_channel('Название', category=category)
```

Или вызываем этот же метод напрямую у категории (все это есть в документации):

```py
await category.create_text_channel('Название')
```