# Как сделать канал доступный только администрации и одному участнику? Discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть такая команда:

```
author = ctx.message.author
guild = bot.get_guild(айди)
role = guild.get_role(айди)
category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=айди)

await author.add_roles(role)
await category.create_text_channel('Тест')
await author.send('Вы были верифицированы...')
```

Я хочу, чтобы созданный канал Тест был приватным и доступен только автору команды.
Также, если можно, я хочу, чтобы канал назывался также, как автор команды.

Comment: Вы хоть [ответ на старый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1459388/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-discord-python) отметьте как решение, чтобы он не висел открытым. Если нужно настроить права доступа — открывайте документацию и ищите у класса канала метод установки прав. Название как ник у автора команды — ищите в документации свойство, возвращающее имя пользователя. На данный момент вы просто "хотите" и все. В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: Не умеете пользоваться документацией — почитайте [**руководство**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-discord-py)

Comment: @denisnumb как отметить сообщение как решённое я не знаю;
Насчёт руководства - да, мой ответ - да, я не умею им пользоваться. Я уже пытался почитать во время решения прошлого вопроса, это обитель Сатаны, но точно не понятно. Мне абсолютно непонятно, как я должен там найти то, что мне нужно, и, если не сложно, отправьте мне ссылку на то, что я попросил.

Comment: @denisnumb про название я написал так, это не суть проблемы. Я не знаю как делать приватные каналы, причём с доступом не у ролей, а у конкретного человека

Comment: @denisnumb, галочку найти не могу. 
И да, как получить айди только что созданного канала? Он нужен мне, чтобы получить объект канала и ему настраивать права.

Comment: @denisnumb, галочки у меня между закладкой и стрелочкой просто нету

Comment: @denisnumb насчёт возвращает я не понял вообще ничего от слова совсем не понял. Куда возвращает то?

Comment: Туда, откуда вызвали. Функции обычно пишут для того, чтобы они **принимали** какие-то данные, что-то с ними делали, а затем **возвращали** результат **туда, откуда их вызвали**. Давайте не будем устраивать обсуждение в комментариях, они для этого не предназначены

Comment: @denisnumb какой туда откуда вызвали, если это команда? В bot чтоли? Моя не понимать

Comment: Давайте продолжим обсуждение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140101/discord-pyth)

Comment: @denisnumb я бы рад да репутации недостаточно

Comment: @denisnumb, ты пропал?

Comment: напиши мне лучше в дс, если что там отвечу `dennys#5895`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался как:

```
author = ctx.message.author
guild = bot.get_guild(айди сервера)
role = guild.get_role(айди роли)
category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=айди категории)

await author.add_roles(role)
channel = await category.create_text_channel(name=author.name)

everyone = everyone = guild.get_role(айди_сервера)
await channel.set_permissions(author, read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
await channel.set_permissions(everyone, read_messages=False, send_messages=False)
```